# Kendo grid excel file downloaded multiple times on clicking excel button

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to display hidden column while exporting to excel.I am using below function to achieve functionality. Issue is it is downloading multiple excel files as it is calling triggering call to 'Insurance/GetInsuranceDisputes' multiple times...If i remove custom code to export hidden column then it works fine by downloading excel only once. let me know what am  I doing wrong

```
 excelExport: function (e) {
                    if (exportFlag) {

                        e.sender.showColumn("INS_TYPE");
                        e.sender.showColumn("ErollementYear");

                        e.preventDefault();
                        exportFlag = true;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                        });
                    } else {
                        e.sender.hideColumn(0);
                        exportFlag = false;
                    }
                }

Here is complete code for binding

var baseUrl = $('base').attr('href');
var gridReadUrl = baseUrl + 'Insurance/GetInsuranceDisputes';

var exportFlag = true;
$(document).ready(function () {

    InsuranceGrid.Initialize('#ActiveGrid');
    var grid = $("#ActiveGrid").data("kendoGrid");


});

var InsuranceGrid = function () {
    var initialize = function () {

        var grid = $("#ActiveGrid"); //$('div', container);

        var filterOption = {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    eq: "Is Equal To",
                    startswith: "Starts With",
                    contains: "Contains",
                    endswith: "Ends With"
                }
            }
        };

        var columnOptions = [

               {
                   field: "INS_NO",
                   title: "INS#",
                   width: 100,
                   filterable: true,
                   editable: false,
                   locked: true
               },
             {
                 field: "INS_TYPE",
                 title: "Insurance Type",
                 width: 250,
                 filterable: false,
                 hidden: true
             },
              {
                  field: "ErollementYear",
                  title: "EnrollmentYear",
                  width: 200,
                  filterable: false,
                  editable: false,
                  hidden: true
             },

        ];
 var gridOptions = {
            toolbar: ["excel"],
            excel: {
                fileName: "InsuranceList.xlsx",
                allPages: true,
                filterable: true
            },
            dataSource: {
                error: function (e) {
                    if (e.errors != false) {
                        alert("Error:" + e.errors);
                        grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault(); // cancel grid rebind
                        });
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: gridReadUrl,
                        type: "POST",
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //alert('ere');
                        },
                        data: function () {

                            return {};
                        }
                    },
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total",
                    model: {
                        id: "ID",
                        fields: {
                            ID: {
                                editable: false,
                                type: "number"
                            },
                            INS_NO: {
                                editable: false,
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            INS_TYPE: {
                                editable: true,
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            ErollementYear: {
                                editable: true,
                                type: "string"
                            },

                       }

                    }
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true
            }
            , dataBound: dataBoundGrid 
            , columns: columnOptions,

            height: 650,
            sortable: {
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: false
            },   
            filterable: true,
            selectable: true,
            change: onChange,

            pageable: {
                pageSize: 20,
                refresh: true,
                messages: {
                    refresh: "Refresh the grid"
                }
            },

            excelExport: function (e) {
                if (exportFlag) {
                    debugger;
                    e.sender.showColumn("INS_TYPE");
                    e.sender.showColumn("ErollementYear");

                    e.preventDefault();
                    exportFlag = true;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                    });
                } else {
                    e.sender.hideColumn(0);
                    exportFlag = false;
                }
            }

        };
        var onClose = function () {
        };

        grid.kendoGrid(gridOptions).delegate("tbody>tr", "dblclick", function (e) { GotoDetailView(e) });

    };
    var dataBoundGrid = function () {

        var grid = new $("#ActiveGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var data = grid.dataSource.data();
        $.each(data, function (i, row) {

            var INSType = row.INS_TYPE;
            if (INSType == "CLOSED") {

                $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').css("background-color", "#990000"); //red
            }
            else {
                $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').css("background-color", "#ff5c33"); //orange
            }
        });

    };
var refresh = function () {
        var grid = $('#ActiveGrid');
        if (grid.length < 1) {
            return;
        }
        grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    };
    return {
        Initialize: initialize,
        Refresh: refresh,

    };
}();


function GotoDetailView(e) {
    var grid = $("#ActiveGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    window.location = baseUrl + "Details/Index?ID=" + ID;

}

function onChange(e) {

    var model = this.dataItem(this.select());
    ID = model.ID;
}
```